# Apply coupon to grouped SKU

Tags: magento-1.7, coupon

I have products where multiple grouped products have the same simple product.

Simple Product SKU: prod1_1

Grouped Product1 SKU: group1_1 - associated product: prod1_1
Grouped Product2 SKU: group2_2 - associated product: prod1_1

I want to set up a coupon rule that will only apply to group1_1/prod1_1, but not group2_2/prod1_1. From what I've seen, the coupon code only seems to apply to the simple product. Is there a setting I'm missing, or would that be something custom?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible 'out of the box', because when adding a part of the grouped product to the cart there is no direct reference to the grouped product for the quote item table. The reference is serialized in the item options (see below).
Honestly, from my point of view, it doesn't even make sense because the following 3 scenarios have the same result.
**Scenario 1**
The customer views the page for `group1_1` and adds to cart product `prod1_1`.
**Scenario 2**
The customer views the page for `group2_2` and adds to cart product `prod1_1`.
**Scenario 3**
The customer views the page for `prod1_1` (if visible) and adds the product to cart.
In all of these 3 cases the customer will buy the same product and the moral thing is to give him/her the discount.
but if you still insist on doing it, here is how I would do it. It's not simple, I'm not sure it will work but it seams like the way to go.
When adding part of a group product to the cart remember in an additional field in `sales_flat_quote_item` (you should add the field) then try to create a new rule criteria to take into consideration your new field.
The hints I can give you are :

1. You can try to use this event `sales_quote_product_add_after`. For
   each item passed to that event in the item options you should find
   the only reference to the grouped product. In field
   `info_buyRequest`. (see how `$item->getOptions()` looks like).
2. To be able to add a new field for rule conditions under *Product
   attribute combination->Cart Item attribute* similar to  *Price in
   cart* or *Quantity in cart* you need to override
   `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product::_addSpecialAttributes()`

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. My plan was actually to overwrite the rules modules slightly and have it check $item->getParent()/getParentId() as well as the sku.

Comment: But since the parentID gets changed each time a different grouped with the same simple gets added to the cart, it's a moot point. Though the way we have the store set up, most people won't buy the same simple from different grouped at the same time.

Comment: You cant use parent_id with grouped products. There is no parent_id added to the quote item when you add a grouped product to the cart. That's what I was saying in my answer.

Comment: Sure there is. Well, not exactly parentID, but there is $item->getParentItem(). I use it in other scripts when manually creating orders, to add the quote item to the order.